# What does super.build_phase() do?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

According to uvm users guide 1.1, page 62:

"If the UVM field automation macros are used, super.build_phase() is called as the first line of the
ubus_example_tb’s build_phase() function. This updates the configuration fields of the
ubus_example_tb."

```
 class ubus_example_tb extends uvm_env;
 ...
 ...
 // build_phase()
 virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
 super.build_phase(phase); // Configure before creating the
 // subcomponents
 ...
 endclass : ubus_example_tb
```

Why the "super.buildphase(phase)" updates ubus_example_tb and not his parent(super)?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not use the `` `uvm_component_utils_begin() `` macro, you should not call `super.build_phase()` in the class that directly extends from `uvm_component`. That creates unnecessary overhead. If you do use the macro, that macros inserts a virtual function that gets called from `uvm_component::build_phase`. That is what gets called from super.build_phase.

I strongly recommend against using the field macros as they are very inefficient. See [this post](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/uvm-utility-macros#reply-68981) that shows how 1 line of code expands to 50.

Also be careful with the terms *parent* and *super*. I recommend against using parent and child when referring to OOP inheritance. Parents create(construct) children and they are distinct objects from their parents. When you inherit property, that property becomes yours and all your property belongs to one object. Use base and extended.

The UVM uses terms parent and child to refer to relationships between objects when build a hierarchical tree/graph structure. The class uvm_component has a handle to its parent and handles to all its children so that you can traverse the hierarchical structure. This terminology is used in most programming languages and is independent of OOP.